Is there anything special about this value?
So.  I was looking at Euler's identity, and also the definition of the imaginary number $i$:
$$e^{i\pi} = -1$$
$$i^2 = -1$$
They are both $-1$.  If we replace $i$ with $x$, and then solve, we get a real number solution:
$$e^{x\pi} = x^2$$
$$x = -\frac{2W(\pm\pi/2)}{\pi}$$
$$x \approx -0.4745…,\space x =-i$$
Those values seem to be special because they share that characteristic with $i$.  Thoughts?
P.S. The answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4967590/736607 below indicates there are an infinite number of branches of the $W$ function, but only $W_0$ has a real value for $-\frac{2W(\pm\pi/2)}{\pi}$.  Since there is only one real value, that value is special.

Did you make a mistake in your calculation?  Numerically finding the real root of $e^{x\pi} = x^2$ gives $x \approx -0.4745409995126511$.

Special as in how?

If x ic in C why not x=i?  and what so characteristic? And your solutions seem wrong?

@Dan Cut-and-paste error.  Correcting.

@TymaGaidash Interesting or cool?

$$e^{\pi x}=x^2$$
with $\text{csgn}$ the complex signum function:
$$\left(e^{\pi x}\right)^\frac{1}{2}=\text{csgn}(x)\ x$$
$\forall x\neq 0$:
$$\frac{\left(e^{\pi x}\right)^\frac{1}{2}}{\text{csgn}(x)}=x$$
That means your two values are only two of the infinite number of fixed points of the function $$\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}\to\mathbb{C}, x\to \frac{\left(e^{\pi x}\right)^\frac{1}{2}}{\rm{csgn}(x)}.$$
$+i$, for example, is a further fixed point.
$$x=-\frac{2W_k(\pm\pi/2)}{\pi}\ \ \ (\forall k\in\mathbb{Z})$$
None of the branches of Lambert W is an elementary function. There is no simple general method to decide for which arguments Lambert W yields an algebraic number or an elementary number.
for the number of real solutions:
Look at the graph of the real branches of Lambert W ($W_{-1},W_0$) at the Wikipedia article. The range of both branches together is whole $\mathbb{R}$. The ranges of all branches of Lambert W are disjoint. It follows that no branch except $W_{-1}$ and $W_0$ has real values. That means $-\frac{2W_0(+\pi/2)}{\pi}$ is the only real solution of your equation.
You can see this also from the zeros in the graph of the function $x\mapsto e^{\pi x}-x^2$ at Wolfram Alpha - there is only one.
$-\frac{2}{\pi}W_0(\pi/2)=-.474540999512651123017467944048...$
$W_0(\pi/2)=0.745407258948051210754871332507...$
Maybe the Inverse Symbolic Calculator can help.

Are any of the other fixed points reals?

I think that point actually answers my question.  Since that it the only real solution, it is indeed special.

Let indicate $z=x+iy$ then
$$e^{\pi z}=z^2 \iff e^{\pi x}=x^2+y^2 \;\land \; \tan(\pi y)=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$$
that is
$$y=\pm \sqrt{e^{\pi x}-x^2}\tag 1$$
$$\tan(\pm \pi \sqrt{e^{\pi x}-x^2})=\frac{\pm 2x\sqrt{e^{\pi x}-x^2} }{2x^2-e^{\pi x}}\tag 2$$
which numerically, solving $(2)$ for $x$ and then finding $y$ from $(1)$, leads also to complex solution as for example
$$z=0.684582746769613\ldots+i \;2.849920288150724666\ldots $$
For the real solution, when $y=0$ solution is given from $(1)$ by $e^{\pi x}-x^2=0$ and for the purely imaginary solution when $x=0$ from $(1)$ we obtain $y=\pm 1$ and $(2)$ holds.
